# Calling a base class method from a derived class method in Python

Tags: python, inheritance, base-class

I have a class A and I have inherited a class B from class A.
I have two methods methodX & methodY in ClassA. This methodY will be calling methodX in classA.
Now I have a methodZ in ClassB.

The following is the scenario:-

```
class A(object):
 def methodX(self):
  ....
 def methodY(self):
  methodX()

class B(A)
 def methodZ(self):
  self.methodY() #says the global methodX is not defined
```

My question is that I have to call methodY which inturn calls methodX from methodZ. How is it possible? Should I define the methodX globally ? Or is there any other alternative..
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it has been said before, using self.methodX() seems to be solving your problem.
Check this:

```
class A(object):
    def methodX(self):
        print "A.methodX"
    def methodY(self):
        print "A.methodY"
        self.methodX()

class B(A):
    def methodZ(self):
        print "B.methodZ"
        self.methodY()

b = B()
b.methodZ()
```

Generates this output:

```
$ python test.py
B.methodZ
A.methodY
A.methodX
$
```

Which I think it's what you were looking for...

Answer (score 3):

In `methodY` you should be calling `self.methodX()`.

Comment: Sorry..That was a typo here. I have called it in the same manner only: self.methodX().

Comment: @user2234700 If that was true, you wouldn't have got the "global name" error. Please post your actual code.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Actually the methodX() I've reffered here is an event handler and I'm calling that in methodY(). It's a Sikuli code.The method call from methodY() goes like this : onChange(10,methodX) where methodX() is the eventhandler

Comment: @user2234700 - If that's the case I'd say there's something else going on with your code outside of the snippet you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Since a member function cannot be called without using the object of that class, this error is thrown. Using

```
self.methodX()
```

Calls the function `methodX()` using the object using the object used to call the `methodY()`